# Numpy: How to get topN elements for each row efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I try to get the topN list of (index, value) tuples for each row.

**heapq** only use single core during the process,
then I try to use **multiprocessing** but got longer time consumption.

Is there a faster way to get the result ?

Thanks

```
import heapq
import multiprocessing
import numpy
import time


class C1:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = numpy.random.rand(100, 50000)
        self.top_n = 5000

    def run_normal(self):
        output = []
        for item_index in range(self.data.shape[0]):
            objs = heapq.nlargest(self.top_n, enumerate(self.data[item_index]), lambda x: x[1])
            output.append(objs)

    def run_mp(self):
        with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
            output = pool.map(self.sort_arr, self.data.tolist())

    def sort_arr(self, arr):
        return heapq.nlargest(self.top_n, enumerate(arr), lambda x: x[1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c1 = C1()

    start = time.time()
    c1.run_normal()
    print(time.time() - start)

    start = time.time()
    c1.run_mp()
    print(time.time() - start)
```

output

```sh
3.2407033443450928 # for-loop time
12.387788534164429 # multiprocessing time
```

Comment: On my machine I get 4.46 and 4.16 respectively, so multiprocessing *does* bring an improvement

Comment: Also, consider using `timeit.timeit(c1.run_mp, number=1)` for measuring elapsed time.

Answer (score 2):

To state the problem clearly:

We are given an M x N numpy array containing our datapoints. We want to obtain an M x k, where each row contains the top k values from our original array paired with the index of value in its original row.

For example: for an input of [[1, 2], [4, 3], [5, 6]] and k = 1, we would like to output [[(0, 1)], [(1, 3)], [(0, 5)]].

### The Solution

The best and fastest solution is to use native numpy functionality. The strategy is to first grab the top indices per row, then grab the elements from those indices, then combine the two into our output array.

```
data = np.random(100, 50000)  # large
k = 5

# Define the type of our output array elements: (int, float)
dt = np.dtype([('index', np.int32, 1), ('value', np.float64, 1)])

# Take the indices of the largest k elements from each row
top_k_inds = np.argsort(data)[:, -1:-k - 1:-1]

# Take the values at those indices
top_k = np.take_along_axis(data, top_k_inds, axis=-1)

# Stack the two together along a third axis (to get index-value pairs)
top_k_pairs = np.stack((top_k_inds, top_k), axis=2)

# Convert the type (otherwise we have the indices as floats)
top_k_pairs = top_k_pairs.astype(dt)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the top n rows easily with numpy.argsort:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.rand(100, 50000)
top_n = 5000

indices = np.argsort(data)[:, :top_n]
top_data = data[:, indices]
```

This is faster than performing the iteration directly in Python.